# provider.logRetentionInDays not working as expected

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless, serverless-architecture, serverless-application-model

I am using serverless framework version 2.11.0

When trying to deploy, it is throwing serverless error:

```
Configuration error at 'provider.logRetentionInDays': should be equal to one of the allowed values
```

But it is not showing any allowed values.
Also in my case I am giving the value as 90 (Integer).
Anything which I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you share the code? It should work for integer value, I'm using it with value set to 30 and it works great. Probably the problem is caused by something else.

Comment: Found the issue, even though I was setting it to integer, it was somehow taking string and that was the root cause. Thanks

Comment: Cool, you can actually answer your own question and mark it as the answer, so if somebody will be facing the same problem, then your post might be helpful. Just please provide an example :)

Answer (score 8):

I got same warning when I used the value as 2 (Integer). I checked in aws cloudwatch log retention settings. It lists some options as [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kC5Pb.png). Then I changed the value to 3, which is in the list, the warning message was disappeared.

Comment: That worked! Any idea how to set it to "Never expire"?

Comment: @megapixel23 if you don't define this field, I think it will never expire

Comment: @Theo is correct. If you don't set this attribute, then by default log group has "Never Expire" retention.

Answer (score 1):

The serverless plugin for setting logRetention internally uses the PutRetentionPolicy AWS api to set up the logRetentionPolicy by which we can set up a retention period. The api accepts only a set of valid values for the retention days as you can see in this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_PutRetentionPolicy.html#:%7E:text=The%20number%20of%20days%20to%20retain%20the%20log%20events%20in%20the%20specified%20log%20group.%20Possible%20values%20are%3A%201%2C%203%2C%205%2C%207%2C%2014%2C%2030%2C%2060%2C%2090%2C%20120%2C%20150%2C%20180%2C%20365%2C%20400%2C%20545%2C%20731%2C%201827%2C%202192%2C%202557%2C%202922%2C%203288%2C%20and%203653.).

Also to make it never expire we simply don't have to set it to any logRetentionPolicy. ([Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteRetentionPolicy.html#:%7E:text=Log%20events%20do%20not%20expire%20if%20they%20belong%20to%20log%20groups%20without%20a%20retention%20policy.))